# Dotplot: How to change dot sizes of dotplot based on a value in data and make all x axis values into whole numbers

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have made a dotplot for my data but need to help with the finishing touches. Been around stackoverflow a bit and haven't seen any posts that directly answer my queries yet.

My code for my dotplot is:

```
ggplot()+
geom_dotplot(mapping = aes(x= reorder(Description, -p.adjust), y=Count, fill=-p.adjust),
             data = head(X[which(X$p.adjust < 0.05),], n = 15), binaxis = 'y', dotsize = 2,
            method = 'dotdensity', binpositions = 'all', binwidth = NULL)+
  scale_fill_continuous(low="black", high="light grey") +
  labs(y = "Associated genes", x = "wikipathways", fill = "p.adjust") +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=8)) +
  ggtitle('') +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(2, face = "bold", hjust = 1),
        legend.key.size = unit(2, "line")) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white', colour = 'black'))+
  coord_fixed(ratio = 0.5)+
  coord_flip()
```

Let's say the X is something along the lines of:

```
   Description   p.adjust  Count   GeneRatio  
1  DescriptionA  0.001     3       3/20
2  DescriptionB  0.002     2       2/20
3  DescriptionC  0.003     5       5/20
4  DescriptionD  0.004     10      10/20
```

To complete this plot I need two edits.

I would like to use base the size of the dots on the GeneRatio, and make a secondary key based around this size. Is this possible with ggplot2, dotplots?

Next I would like to keep the X axis values as integers. I'd want to avoid using something like scale_x_continuous(limits = c(2, 10)) as this plot code is part of a function for multiple data sets of various sizes. Thus containing the limits/scale would not work well.

Help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can switch to a geom_point chart instead of geom_dotplot it's easy to adjust the dot size according to a variable. It also seems to have corrected your axis issue luckily enough.

```
ggplot(x)+
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x= reorder(Description, -p.adjust), y=Count, fill=-p.adjust, size=GeneRatio),
               data = head(x[which(x$p.adjust < 0.05),], n = 15), binaxis = 'y', #dotsize = 2,
               method = 'dotdensity', binpositions = 'all', binwidth = NULL)+
  scale_fill_continuous(low="black", high="light grey") +
  labs(y = "Associated genes", x = "wikipathways", fill = "p.adjust") +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=8)) +
  ggtitle('') +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(2, face = "bold", hjust = 1),
    legend.key.size = unit(2, "line")) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white', colour = 'black'))+
  coord_fixed(ratio = 0.5)+
  coord_flip()
```